# Get mail from Gmail Inbox with LumiSoft - C#

Tags: c#, gmail, pop3, lumisoft

How can I get the contents of all of the emails in a Gmail inbox with the Lumisoft Net library?  I have already successfully connected to Gmail with my application, but I cannot seem to be able to get the actual contents of an email, although I can get the MIME header.

Here's my current code:

```
foreach (POP3_ClientMessage message in client.Messages)
{
    Stream msgStream = new MemoryStream(message.Size);
    message.MessageToStream(msgStream.Size);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(msgStream);
    MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/Net/Help/html/ecea18a0-ec66-211f-4d0c-9093bc8c5ff5.htm), it looks like this should be:

```
foreach (POP3_ClientMessage message in client.Messages)
{
    Stream msgStream = new MemoryStream(message.Size);
    message.MessageToStream(msgStream);
    msgStream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(msgStream);
    MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Your code probably wouldn't compile- it passes `msgStream.Size` to the `MessageToStream` method, which takes a `Stream` as an argument.  Also, you need to set the Position to 0 to move the stream back to the beginning before reading it.

Comment: Thanks!  Now all I have to do is find a MIME parser or whatever I need to process the output.

Comment: I don't get why you don't use LumiSoft mime or Mail message parser.